# How do you get video size stream inside AVPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I play the 720x1280 video with AVPlayer. Since the resolutions on the phones are different, how can I find the coordinates of the area where the video is played or the dimensions of the video on the phone?

How can I find the dimensions or coordinates of the region in the orange line in the photo?

```swift
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
playerLayer!.frame = viewPlayer.bounds
viewPlayer.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer!)
player!.play()

print("playerLayer videoRect: (String(describing: playerLayer?.videoRect.width))") print("playerLayer bounds: (String(describing: playerLayer?.bounds))") print("playerLayer frame: (String(describing: playerLayer?.frame))")

let size = videoTrack.naturalSize //this natural video size 720x1280
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: viewPlayer.frame stores coordinates and dimensions. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617836-scale UIScreen.main.scale stores the values of the number of pixels in one point to get the resolution

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        self.playerLayer?.frame = self.viewPlayer.frame
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
 }
```